# Prevent DateTimePicker from autoclose

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-datetimepicker

I have a kendo component kendo-datetimepicker (angular project, kendo-angular)

When I open the calendar, start typing the date (day, month, year) and time (hours, minutes) in the input, right at the end when I select minutes - the calendar closes automatically.

The issue could be checked here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datetimepicker/date-time-limits/

Any way to prevent the calendar from closing?

And close, only when I click on cancel or set button?

Comment: If you're using a DateTimePicker, why type in the time manually? I tested it just now and the dropdown closes right as I start typing, no matter which field I'm entering...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call the [toggle](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/api/DateTimePickerComponent/#toc-toggle) method on the [blur](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/api/DateTimePickerComponent/#toc-blur) event to keep it open.  Stackblitz example [here](https://angular-pp6nzj.stackblitz.io).  setTimeout is needed so that the method is call is put on the stack and does not run immediately.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { DateTimePickerComponent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <p class="col-md-6">
                    <kendo-datetimepicker #datePickerChild
                        (blur)="onBlur()"
                    >
                    </kendo-datetimepicker>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
})

export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('datePickerChild', { static: false })
    public datePickerChild!: DateTimePickerComponent;
    constructor() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.datePickerChild.toggle();
        });
    }

    public onBlur(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.datePickerChild.toggle();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working, but every time it's closing and open (not look so nice)
+ when I click outside, it's not closing